# confusion in total installs vs active installs. 38 total installs suddenly increased to 92 but not active installs

Tags: android, google-play

This might off topic in this forum. sorry for that.

I have uploaded a game 2 weeks back, and till date the total installs were 38 and active was 19.    today i just opened the Dev console, i could see 92 total and 19 active. I didnt understand that if total install can raise but not active installs,  Can anyone please help me on this to understand.
Additional info: last night i updated my game with newer version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, its  updated now with expected active installs, the only problem i could see is android market will take some time to update and there will be a time gap between total installs and active installs to update !!

Comment: This is the normal behavior. The total downloads will show all downloads until the current day. The active downloads are measured a little bit different, it seems that downloads are not counted as active until the app stays one day on the phone of your user. That means if you get a lot of new total downloads expect a lot of new active downloads on the next day. If a user later uninstalls the app the number of active downloads will go down. The total downloads will only decrease if google changes something inside their counting algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

active installs - how many devices use this app (How many installs still currently on device) 
active installs may be reduced 
total install - how many downloads and installs have this app